# Gazebo crashes intermittently (race condition?) when run from roslaunch alongside ROS (gazebo_gui-2, gazebo_gui-3])

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Summary**
Gazebo will crash intermittently *when* I run it from roslaunch *in conjunction* with other ROS nodes

- If I roslaunch a .launch file that starts a .world file via gazebo_ros, Gazebo **does not** crash.
- However, my .launch file also contains a .urdf with plugins (that may use ROS and Gazebo messaging) and some other ROS nodes (containing SMACH finite state machines for example). In this case, Gazebo **does** crash *intermittently*, once every 2 - 10 launches.
- The crashing appears to become **more frequent** (a crash every 2-4 launches) as the number of ROS node's in the launch file goes up.
- My solution is to Ctrl-C the Terminal window and then simply roslaunch the .launch file again. Sometimes I have to repeat this process a couple times. Repeated Gazebo crashes also appear to become more frequent as the number of nodes I'm launching goes up.
- A weird trick, if I:
- $ roslaunch myfile.launch
- and then *immediately* click on my terminal window and *drag-it across my monitor.*
  Gazebo will almost never crash. I have no idea why this works. I just know it does (for me).

**Error Message**
libGL error: failed to create drawable ...
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died ...
https://ibb.co/f93iEb

Also, I think there's a segmentation fault one, but I wasn't able to produce it on demand (as I said, the crashing seems somewhat random / non-deterministic)

**Graphics Card**
I have a non-NVIDIA Graphics Card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360]
```

**Related**
Looking through the forums, there seem to be a number of related questions:

[On startup of gazebo I get intermittent error](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5115/on-startup-of-gazebo-i-get-intermittent-error/?answer=5197#post-id-5197)
*Diagnosis:* ROS or Gazebo threading bug, race condition, graphics card
*Workaround:* Set gazebo_ros debug parameter to true, set node respawn="true" in .launch file

[gazebo crashes immediately using roslaunch after installing gazebo ros packages](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4153/gazebo-crashes-immediately-using-roslaunch-after-installing-gazebo-ros-packages/)
[gazebo_gui-3 error when starting gazebo with roslaunch](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4252/gazebo_gui-3-error-when-starting-gazebo-with-roslaunch/)
*Diagnosis:* gazebo_ros can't handle extra roslaunch __name and __log arguments
*Workaround:* start gazebo from separate terminal with rosrun
*Solution?:* https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/commit/c1681bc009d94cec96bf173adfd2a3d2510c7e5e

**Aside**

When I Ctrl-C the terminal window where I ran roslaunch, I usually get the following [gazebo-2] escalating to SIGTERM message:

```
  [gazebo-2] escalating to SIGTERM
  [rosout-1] killing on exit
  Exception ignored in: <gdb.GdbOutputFile object at 0x7fdbc6477518>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 43, in flush
      def flush(self):
  KeyboardInterrupt
  [master] killing on exit
  shutting down processing monitor...
  ... shutting down processing monitor complete
  done
```

Including this in case it is relevant

**How to run Gazebo without crashing?**
Is there something obvious I'm missing. What's the best way for me to go about diagnosing/fixing this problem?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17998/gazebo-crashes-intermittently-(race-condition?)-when-run-from-roslaunch-alongside-ros-(gazebo_gui-2,-gazebo_gui-3%5D)/) by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 609 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Update:**
The easiest fix appears to be to use a NVIDIA Graphics Card. Teammate has been running exact same launch files on his machine w/o any problems.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0